# Excel - update link based on time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

The formula does no reference to online directory, static text is fine. Please find my [not working] solution below.

Hello dearest community,

I am using a formula to count how many rows are used in an online spreadsheet.
The online spreadsheet has sheets based on year - 2022/2023 etc.

My formula is working fine, when I have direct link to a specific  sheet:
=COUNTA('Address.com[Database.xlsx]2023'!$B:$B)
but when I try to have the link as a formula:
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'Address.com[Database.xlsx]"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy")&"'!$B:$B"))
it seems to count it as a text.

Could you please help me out?
thanks so a lot!

Comment: Not sure how you build that spreadsheet but as far as I know can't contain some special chars like `[ ]` so that could explain why your formula does not work. Check [Rename a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-worksheet-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9). Actually, renaming the worksheet could help to INDIRECT

Comment: Name doesn;t contain [ ]. It is just like Excel work - when you add link to another file, name (not path) must be wrapped in [ ]